# Where do couples who are non-UK citizens register the birth of their child in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, birth-certificate

My family and I live in the UK; we are not UK citizens. We had a baby born in the UK recently. Where do I register the birth of our baby in the UK? My wife was told to make an appointment with our GP, but information I found [here](https://www.gov.uk/register-birth) seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that one must register for the birth of a child at the Register Office, not the GP. The child has to be registered with the GP, but this is for health services.

I did not make an appointment at the Register Office in advance, but I was able to get an appointment on the same day. The whole process at the Register Office took about half an hour. I was only asked for a proof of identity; no other documents were required.

A short version of the birth certificate, which was handwritten, was given for free. This contains only the child's details, but does not contain the parents' details. A long version can be purchased; this is typed and contains the parents' details in addition to the child's details.

As far as I can see, there is nothing more to it for the non citizens than for the citizens. For further information, see https://www.gov.uk/register-birth.

Comment: Congratulations on the birth of your child :) You should also contact the embassy of the country that you are citizens of as you may have to register your child at the embassy too. (This is the case for South Africans and may be for others.)